# Doctrine with eAccelerator issue in zend framework 2 website

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2, eaccelerator

The problem that I am getting with the website bulid in zend framework2 with Doctrine 2 as ORM.It works perfect on local server .But its giving me error when deployed on production live server.below is the error

"Class X is not a valid entity or mapped super class"

Can anyone have any solution for it.

Comment: you do know eaccelerator is a dead project... no updates since nearly 2 years.

Comment: oh and to your problem... clear your caches... (specially the doctrine proxies)

Comment: I have cleared all doctrine proxies caches,but dont work . one thing that i found is eaccelerator is enabled on my production server.Is that eaccelerator causing any error.

Answer (score 1):

I covered this in [a blog post](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/eaccelerator-and-doctrine-2) a while back. Basically, this is happening because eAccelerator is stripping out docblock annotations as an "optimisation". The problem is that Doctrine is relying on these annotations to map your entities.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Don't use eAccelerator. There are much better opcache tools available e.g. [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or PHP's built-in [OPcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) (PHP 5.5+).
2. Disable this behaviour in eAccelerator. You can do this by compiling eAccelerator with the `--with-eaccelerator-doc-comment-inclusion` flag, *or* use a newer version of eAccelerator which disables this behaviour by default.